# django session ,the function must return the session can be modifyed?

Tags: django, session

```
@dajaxice_register
def sendMailByIndex(request,confid,mailentyid,start_id,count):
    dajax = Dajax()
    for i in range(1,100000):
        print request.session.session_key
        request.session['percent']=i
        time.sleep(1)
    return dajax.json()
@dajaxice_register
def getProgress(request):
    dajax = Dajax()
    print request.session.session_key
    print request.session['percent']
    dajax.add_data(random.randint(1,100), 'recProgress')
    return dajax.json()
```

In the function `sendMailByIndex` I want to change the `session['percent']`, it will be running for a long time. Then I want to call getProgress to get the progress.
But it doesn't work, the `session['percent']` doesn't change?
How to change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default sessions are saved to the database at the end of the request. Call `save` explicitly:

```
@dajaxice_register
def sendMailByIndex(request, confid, mailentyid, start_id, count):
    dajax = Dajax()
    for i in range(1, 100000):
        print request.session.session_key
        request.session['percent'] = i
        request.session.save()
        time.sleep(1)
    return dajax.json()
```